Selecting the appropriate RDS instance in AWS
I am currently using a db.r6g.4xlarge instance which is very expensive for me $2.1 per hour. Resource usage except RAM is very low.
My current average load on the db.r6g.4xlarge instance is: BinLogDiskUsage = 60M, CPUUtilization = 15%, DatabaseConnections = 100, DBLoad = 3, DBLoadCPU = 2, DBLoadNonCPU = 2, DiskQueueDepth = 1, FreeableMemory = 15G, LVMReadIOPS = 10, LVMWriteIOPS - 2k.
I would like to change the instance from db.r6g.4xlarge to db.r7g.2xlarge.
db.r6g.4xlarge:

vCPU: 16
RAM: 128 GiB

db.r7g.2xlarge:

vCPU: 8
RAM: 64 GiB

Is this possible or not because of the RAM (FreeableMemory at 128 GiB is only 15 GiB)?


Which database engine are you using? Are you using Amazon Aurora? Databases love having lots of RAM, which is why the R-family is often used with Amazon RDS. A lack of memory will lead to more swapping to disk. You can certainly change to a different instance type. You'll just need to monitor it to ensure it is providing sufficient performance.

@JohnRotenstein I'm using MariaDB. Thank you for reply!
